# Not getting fields prefilled with previous values while editing a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form(EditProfileForm) which I created to edit the profile details. My issue is that whenever I go to the EditProfileForm page in the browser the fields are not filled with previous values which I gave while making the profile for the first time, I have to fill the entire form however if I make some change in the value then the change is being made successfully.

my Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='profile_pic.jpg', upload_to='profile_pictures') 
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

my EditProfileForm in forms.py:

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
 
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image', 'location', 'bio']
```

my two views regarding profile and edit profile:

```
@login_required
def profile_page(request):
    user = request.user
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=user)
    posts_count = posts.count()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
    return render(request, 'blog_app/profile.html', {'user': user, 'posts_count': posts_count, 'profile': profile})

def edit_profile(request, id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.FILES, instance=profile)
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():

            # deleting old uploaded image.
            image_path = profile.image.path
            if os.path.exists(image_path):
                os.remove(image_path)

            # the `form.save` will also update the newest image & path.
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
                 
    return render(request, 'blog_app/edit_profile.html', {'profile': profile, 'form': form})
```

my two urls about profile and edit profile:

```
path('profile', user_views.profile_page, name='profile'),
path('edit_profile/<int:id>', user_views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile')
```

By the way I used django signals to automatically create profile for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The way I work with `ModelForm` is:

```py
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
```

I don't know what is actually the difference between these two statements:

```py
form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
```

and

```py
form = EditProfileForm(request.FILES, instance=profile)
```

But, You can try with this.
You can replace the `edit_profile(request, id)` function with this:

```py
def edit_profile(request, id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():

            # deleting old uploaded image.
            image_path = profile.image.path
            if os.path.exists(image_path):
                os.remove(image_path)

            # the `form.save` will also update the newest image & path.
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
                 
    return render(request, 'blog_app/edit_profile.html', {'profile': profile, 'form': form})
```

Comment: In your answser if you are assigning the same value to the variable form i.e "EditProfileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)" , then why are you using if and else conditions if the values are same and also why would you pass request.POST in the if condition as it will only trigger when the method is not post. Please do reply, I am new to django so may be i am wrong.

Comment: Actually, you can remove the `if` `else` condition. I am not so expert on it. But it works correctly for me. Yes, you are right, the conditionals should remove. I am updating my answer. But, is it work for you or not (May there could be another reason that I don't know)?